# My Tor Download Speed is Awful

Tags: configuration

I'm using tor browser version "tor-browser-linux64-6.0.7" in ubuntu14.4. But its speed is awful. In addition while it's downloading a file, it uses a great amount of my Internet traffic compared to the size of the file. Similarly, while opening a website, it consumes much Internet traffic, compared to the traffic needed for that website to be opened without Tor. Since Tor is censored in my country, in answer to question

Does your Internet Service Provider (ISP) block or otherwise censor connections to the Tor Network?

I checked Yes option, and it uses obfs4 as the bridge to connect to Tor. Any other settings of my Tor are configured to their defaults.

Is there any way to speed up my Tor? Do I have to make some special configuration to my Tor to overcome this problem? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The default obfs4 bridges are normally heavily overused, they're the easiest to configure because they're built in which is great for accessibility but it means that most users use only a small set of obfs4 servers and so their resources are overstretched and as such the speed is reduced.

You would (likely) see an improvement if you fetched some bridges from [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/), choosing the option for obfs4 and entered the bridge lines it gives you into Tor Browser under the custom bridges option during the configuration. The lines that BridgeDB provides should just be pasted into the provided text box exactly as BridgeDB presents them.

You should definitely see better performance from those bridges because there will be less contention of their resources.